# POSTing strings to C# AWS Lambda via Postman

Tags: c#, aws-lambda

I'm digging into the dotnet new templates for Lambdas in AWS and I'm hitting my head against the proper way to pass string data via Postman (or any web client really).

I'm using the Lambda Empty Function template from AWS. Just a `dotnet new lambda.EmptyFunction` with the only changes being to the lambda-tools file to point at my AWS credentials and region. Deploy works fine. Invoking the function from the local terminal via the global tools works fine:

```
dotnet-lambda invoke-function lambda-hello-empty --payload "test"
```

In the AWS Console, using the Test function also works with a value of just `test` with no strings or JSON wrappers.

I added an API Gateway and am trying to make the same call via Postman with an HTTP post, but every call has failed with this error:

> Error converting the Lambda event JSON payload to a string. JSON strings must be quoted, for example "Hello World" in order to be converted to a string: The JSON value could not be converted to System.String

I've got a separate API Gateway added the same way that isn't accepting a parameter and just returning a string and that works, so I don't think the issue is with the gateway.

I'm sure there's a step I'm missing here with proper serialization but I can't see it. It clearly works from the AWS consoles but since I don't know what they might be doing to format things, I want to see this work "raw".

Comment: just a guess, does `'"test"'` instead of `"test"` works?

Comment: No, it still fails to parse the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there's some additional metadata expected somewhere in the API Gateway / Lambda stack that I was missing. By having my startup class derive from Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction, I was able to get the request working through Postman and through other applications.

Comment: This simple change was what I was hoping for, but it did not work for me. Are you saying you just literally changed the 1 line public class Function : APIGatewayProxyFunction {
and then added the necessary nuget package and it worked?

Comment: I think that was all it took, but it was a year ago so I'm not certain.